# Can I call all methods of an object?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object:

```
var shapes = {
     addTriangle: function(color){
         console.log("added " + color + " triangle");
     },
     addSquare: function(color){
         console.log("added " + color + " square");
     }
}
```

This object will have methods that will be changed and updated frequently, but all the methods will always be running sequentially. Is there a way to automatically get and run all the methods, to ease maintainability?
Something like:

```
function runShapes(color){
    shapeNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(shapes);
    for(i = 0; i < shapeNames.length; i++){
        shapeNames[i].apply(color);
    }
}
```

This gives `shapeNames[i].apply is not a function'. Bonus points for telling me how to do this with functional programming, instead of a for loop :)

Codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJxVyE

Comment: `shapes` != `Shapes`, but apart from that, have you tried it?

Comment: yeah, gives the listed error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off your mistake... You are iterating through the property names and not the properties.

```
shapeNames[i].apply(color);
```

should be:

```
shapes[shapeNames[i]](color);
```

A more functional version might look like this:

```
function runShapes(color){
    Object.keys(shapes).forEach(function(each){
        shapes[each](color);
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually it should be `shapes[shapeNames[i]](color);`.

Comment: Please remove `call` and `apply` from your answer, it makes very little sense. A check if property is a function would also be a good idea.

Comment: If it's your object and you know there are only functions, I don't see a reason for the is function check. Object.keys doesn't touch prototype methods.

Comment: Yes, the object will only be functions, so no check needed.

Comment: The functional version gives `uncaught reference error: color is not defined` how do I pass in the color argument in the functional version?

Comment: I left out the wrapper of your runShapes function :)

Answer (score 3):

you have to check that the property you're calling is actually a function:

```
if( typeof shapes[shapeNames[i]] === "function") {
    // your code here
}
```

About the 'functional programming' style, you can use [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which calls the function you pass as parameter on every element of an array. So your code should look like this:

```
function runShapes(color){
    shapeNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(shapes);
    shapeNames.forEach(function(prop) {
        if(typeof shapes[prop] === "function") {
            shapes[prop](color);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: need to remove `.apply` to make it work, but other than that, it's great